# writing to a file based on project location

Tags: c#

I'm writing a C# windows application in Visual Studio. I want to make it so my program saves a file to a folder automatically, based on the folder the program is stored in. I tried Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString(); but access to that is denied to me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try use:

```
string filePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\myfilename.txt";
```

Comment: will gives the Debug folder

Comment: @un-lucky, yes when you are in the debug mode. And it will give you the application folder when you run the .exe from anywhere.

Comment: great... but its marked as A dupe

Comment: You can check the duplicate link, it might give more information.

Answer (score 0):

Check your security permissions. If the are ok, you should have the access. To save the file just

```
  using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = 
            new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines2.txt"))
        {
             file.Write......
        }
```

or

```
 // Create the file.
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
    {
        Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("This is some text in the file.");
        // Add some information to the file.
        fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
    }
```

Comment: Most likely "Access denied" OP is getting is not related to permissions at all... I bet OP tries to use folder name as file name. You may want to clarify such cases (since OP did not provide any code to work from) when answering question in future.